# FB Login API - Checking if the user is actually the user

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            switchTo('loggedin');
            // connected & ok
        });
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        switchTo('loggedout');
        // connected but not ok

        FB.login();
    } 
    else 
    {
        switchTo('loggedout');
        // not connected

        FB.login();
    }
});
```

So here is an ordenary facebook javascript login function.
If the user is connected & verified I  send ajax requests to the server containing the given ID by the `fb.api('/me')`. But anyone could alter the code, and edit the code in a way that they could use someone elses ID and send that to the server.

How do I verify that the user who logged in via javascript is the actual user, and not just someone who altered the code?

Comment: Make the call to `/me` server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty secure way is to use the PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Look at "Usage":

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  //user is logged in
} else {
  //user is not logged in
}
```

For example, you can do a page reload after login with the JS SDK and check with the PHP SDK before you load the page.

Comment: Is it a "pretty secure" way or a "secure" way? What makes it "pretty" secure and how could I improve the security?

Comment: "secure" ;) - especially because it´s all in php.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as you are using **PHP** as a back-end language

I suggest that beside sending user id , you can send id hash salted with some special salt which didn't show in your java script just in your php code

as example

```
var url = "www.example.com/?id=SOME_ID&secret=<?php echo md5(SOME_ID.SECRET)";
```

and in backend

```
 $secret = $_GET['secret'];
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 if (md5($id.SECRET) == $secret){
  //User is ok here 
 }else{
  //Some one missing around
 }
```

This code is for showing up the idea not a complete code to use

Comment: This is hashed secret not a plain secret code like Authorization taken that is used all over the web

Comment: ah, alright, it´s just a plain md5 string. nevertheless, md5 is not secure, and where does the secret on the client come from?

Comment: just look at the answer , client get a black box secret hash coming from server side combined with salt which also server based , and i agree with you that md5 hash is common today , so i used salt and you can also use SHA1 instead , even though am open to hear and benefit of your contribution , Thanks

Comment: so, on page load you genereate a secret in php and pass it on in the url. what happens then? no offense, i just want to understand it. always willing to learn something new :) - right now i just don´t get it, what is the purpose of that hash? when do you use it, when does the backend get called?

Comment: Ok , i generate secret with your id combined with salt so you will send this to back-end to log you in using ajax , suppose that user changed id manually as asker said, then when i run back-end code above i will figure out this is a fake user trying to hijack the id

Comment: ah, now i understand what you mean with "salt" ;) - i am not very experienced in the crypto stuff ;) - well, it makes sense, but still: it´s much better to just use the php sdk. no hash needed, less work, everything in php.